# How to make files unmodifiable and undeletable without `chattr`?

Tags: files, permissions

I (and my collaborators) have a directory tree containing ~160K files (most of them are automatically generated by data gathering instrumentation).

These files reside in a system that gets backed up constantly, and therefore, we are not too worried about data loss or corruption, as long as we have the information required to restore from backup when needed.

We're much more worried about *inadvertent* data loss or corruption resulting from user error (especially buggy user-written code), because this means, at best, wasted work until the problem is detected.

Therefore, we want to make these files undeletable and unmodifiable.

Unfortunately, neither of us has permission to use `chattr` on this system, which rules out applying `chattr +i` to these files.

Is there some other way, not requiring special permissions, to approximate `chattr +i`?

The rest of this post describes a couple of possibilities we've considered, along with their shortcomings.

One possibility would be to apply `chmod -R a-w DATA`, where I've used `DATA` as shorthand for the root of the directory tree in question.

This is fine as a first approximation, but it goes a bit too far, because it renders many operations that we may need to perform occasionally (e.g. consolidating several subdirectories into one)

A second possibility would be something like

```
find DATA -type f -exec chmod a-w {} \;
```

This is a bit more flexible, and the files can no longer be modified, but they can still be deleted.

Comment: You don't have root priviledges then? If you have your data backed up, why the fact that the files can still be deleted is a problem? It won't be modified, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Plus, have you considered using a versioning control?

Comment: @Kira: as I already explained, it is not mere deletion I'm worried about, but rather *inadvertent deletion*, as a result of an error in code or in command-line interaction.  The larger the number of files and/or the more complicated the file tree structure, the easier it becomes for such an unintended change *to go unnoticed*.  The longer such a change goes unnoticed, the more serious the downstream consequences, and many of these consequences (e.g. the wasted work) are not mitigated by having back ups.  In fact, since the backups are kept for only a limited duration, it is even possible ...

Comment: @Kira ... that the data loss is discovered late enough for the backups to no longer be available.

Comment: @Kira: regarding version control, I have considered version control.  Originally I had rejected the idea, because most of the files in this collection are huge binary files containing raw data, the sort of file that are generally considered *not* suitable for version control (or at least for text-oriented version control systems, such as `git`").  After reading your comment, though, I'm now reconsidering `git` for data-integrity enforcement features, rather than its full version control capabilities, as a (hopefully quick) to detect breaches of data integrity.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this without `chattr`.

However, what you **can** do is put the files you don't want to be modified or deleted in a separate directory, make that directory non-writeable (e.g. `chmod og-w DIR`) and the files in it read-only (e.g. `chmod 644 DIR/*`)

This separate directory **must not** be a subdirectory of any directory that the users have write access to, otherwise they will still be able to delete the dir or change its permissions.